# SQL query unknown column

Tags: sql

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   k.*, m.title as city, w.title as state 
FROM 
   konta__kategoria kat, konta k 
INNER JOIN 
   miejscowosci as m ON k.miejscowosc = m.id 
INNER JOIN 
   wojewodztwa as w ON k.wojewodztwo = w.id 
LEFT JOIN 
   kategorie as cat ON cat.id = kat.kategoria 
WHERE 
   kat.kategoria IN (1610,1609,1608,1607,1606,1605,1611,1612,1613,1614,1615,1616,1617,1618,1619,1620,1621,1622,1623,1624,1625,1626,1627,1628,1629,1630,1631,1632,1633,1634,1635,1636,1637,1638,1639,1640,1641,1642,1643,1644,1645,1646,1647,1648,1649,1650,1651,1652,1653,1654,1655,1656,1657,1658,1659,1660,1661,1662,1663,1664,1665,1666,1667,1668,1669,1670,1671,1672,1673,6) 
   AND kat.parent_id = k.id 
   AND k.dsc LIKE "%%" 
   AND deleted = 0 
ORDER BY 
   k.nazwa
```

I'm getting error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'kat.kategoria' in 'on clause'
```

It's working when I remove

```
LEFT JOIN kategorie as cat ON cat.id = kat.kategoria
```

But I know that `kat.kategoria` exist (it's working in where), also there exist table cat.id, so what is the problem?

Comment: Why?! You're using pre and post ANSI 92 `JOIN` syntax in the exact same query. Why would you do that?

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle.com page with the schema and sample data?

Comment: do you get anything from `SELECT DISTINCT kat.kategoria FROM konta__kategoria kat` ?

Comment: Zane-> so how to fix it> Paul H -> yes

Comment: Besides the error (which has been solved by the 2 answers), why are you joining `kategorie as cat`? It seems you don't use that table at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using a pre-ansi join. Here is what's going on: the list of `JOIN`s are "connected" with the last table from the list, namely, the `konta k`. The `konta__kategoria kat` part of the non-ANSI join is not in scope in any of the ANSI joins, triggering the error that you see.

You can fix it by using ANSI joins everywhere, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   k.*, m.title as city, w.title as state 
FROM 
   konta__kategoria kat
CROSS JOIN konta k 
INNER JOIN 
   miejscowosci as m ON k.miejscowosc = m.id 
INNER JOIN 
   wojewodztwa as w ON k.wojewodztwo = w.id 
LEFT JOIN 
   kategorie as cat ON cat.id = kat.kategoria 
WHERE 
   kat.kategoria IN (1610,1609,1608,1607,1606,1605,1611,1612,1613,1614,1615,1616,1617,1618,1619,1620,1621,1622,1623,1624,1625,1626,1627,1628,1629,1630,1631,1632,1633,1634,1635,1636,1637,1638,1639,1640,1641,1642,1643,1644,1645,1646,1647,1648,1649,1650,1651,1652,1653,1654,1655,1656,1657,1658,1659,1660,1661,1662,1663,1664,1665,1666,1667,1668,1669,1670,1671,1672,1673,6) 
   AND kat.parent_id = k.id 
   AND k.dsc LIKE "%%" 
   AND deleted = 0 
ORDER BY 
   k.nazwa
```

Now both `k` and `kat` aliases are in scope for all the joins, so your query should work.

**UPDATE :** Assuming that `id` and `parent_id` are non-nullable, you do not need a cross join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   k.*, m.title as city, w.title as state 
FROM 
   konta__kategoria kat
INNER JOIN
    konta k ON kat.parent_id = k.id
INNER JOIN 
   miejscowosci as m ON k.miejscowosc = m.id 
INNER JOIN 
   wojewodztwa as w ON k.wojewodztwo = w.id 
LEFT JOIN 
   kategorie as cat ON cat.id = kat.kategoria 
WHERE 
   kat.kategoria IN (1610,1609,1608,1607,1606,1605,1611,1612,1613,1614,1615,1616,1617,1618,1619,1620,1621,1622,1623,1624,1625,1626,1627,1628,1629,1630,1631,1632,1633,1634,1635,1636,1637,1638,1639,1640,1641,1642,1643,1644,1645,1646,1647,1648,1649,1650,1651,1652,1653,1654,1655,1656,1657,1658,1659,1660,1661,1662,1663,1664,1665,1666,1667,1668,1669,1670,1671,1672,1673,6) 
   AND k.dsc LIKE "%%" 
   AND deleted = 0 
ORDER BY 
   k.nazwa
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `CROSS JOIN` since the `WHERE` clause has the join condition `kat.parent_id = k.id`. Just make it an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: yeah ... try it with `INNER JOIN ON kat.parent_id = k.id` (and remove that from the `WHERE` clause) instead of `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: @user2606353 then you were not doing it correctly... Did you have the syntax right.

Comment: @user2606353 how did you try it? you'll need to change the syntax according to how i suggested it

Comment: @Zane I've copied your answer and it also works, I don't know why (I've tryed inner join), maybe I made a syntax error, thank you

Answer (score 5):

So this is how that query would be written with the current `JOIN` syntax put forth by ANSI 92. Here is a [Link](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) to a brilliant article as to why you should not use the old method for doing this.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
           k.*, m.title as city, w.title as state 
        FROM 
           konta__kategoria kat
        INNER JOIN konta k 
            ON kat.parent_id = k.id 
        INNER JOIN miejscowosci as m 
            ON k.miejscowosc = m.id 
        INNER JOIN  wojewodztwa as w 
            ON k.wojewodztwo = w.id 
        LEFT JOIN  kategorie as cat 
            ON cat.id = kat.kategoria 
        WHERE 
           kat.kategoria IN (1610,1609,1608,1607,1606,1605,1611,1612,1613,1614,1615,1616,1617,1618,1619,1620,1621,1622,1623,1624,1625,1626,1627,1628,1629,1630,1631,1632,1633,1634,1635,1636,1637,1638,1639,1640,1641,1642,1643,1644,1645,1646,1647,1648,1649,1650,1651,1652,1653,1654,1655,1656,1657,1658,1659,1660,1661,1662,1663,1664,1665,1666,1667,1668,1669,1670,1671,1672,1673,6) 
           AND k.dsc LIKE "%%" 
           AND deleted = 0 
        ORDER BY 
           k.nazwa
```

Comment: I've copied your answer and it also works, I don't know why (I've tryed inner join), maybe I made a syntax error, thank you

Comment: One other question @user2606353 why use `and k.dsc like '%%'`? Those are just two wild cards with no filter at all.

Comment: Yes, `k.dsc LIKE '%%'` is equivalent to `k.dsc IS NOT NULL` - and if `k.dsc` is not nullable, you can remove the condition.